# HttpTestingController expectOne always failing with none found in Angular component test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, frontend, jasmine, httpclient

I have this Angular component which makes a simple http request:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
  selector: 'http-requester',
  template: '',
})
export class HttpRequesterComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() url!: string;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe((content) => console.log(content));
  }
}
```

And this test:

```
import {
    HttpClientTestingModule,
    HttpTestingController,
  } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
  import { Spectator, createComponentFactory } from '@ngneat/spectator';
  import { HttpRequesterComponent } from './http-requester.component';
  
  describe('HttpRequesterComponent', () => {
    let spectator: Spectator<HttpRequesterComponent>;
    let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  
    const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
      component: HttpRequesterComponent,
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      detectChanges: false,
    });
  
    beforeEach(() => {
      spectator = createComponent();
      httpTestingController = spectator.inject(HttpTestingController);
    });
  
    afterEach(() => {
      httpTestingController.verify();
    });
  
    it('should call httpClient.get with the provided URL', () => {
      const url = 'https://example.com';
      spectator.component.url = url;
      spectator.detectChanges();
  
      const request = httpTestingController.expectOne(url);
  
      request.flush('Content here');
    });
  });
```

However the test is always failing with "Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://example.com", found none" at the `expectOne` call.

Can anyone help me out and spot why?

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine `spectator.detectChanges();` to call `ngOnInit();` but maybe it's not.

Try calling it explicitly like so:

```
it('should call httpClient.get with the provided URL', () => {
      const url = 'https://example.com';
      spectator.component.url = url;
      spectator.detectChanges();
      // !! explicitly call ngOnInit and see if that works.
      spectator.component.ngOnInit();
      console.log('Expecting http call !!');
      const request = httpTestingController.expectOne(url);
  
      request.flush('Content here');
    });
```

Also, add logs to `ngOnInit()` to see if it was called or not.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // make sure the below line is called ensuring that ngOnInit was called
    // and make sure it was called before Expecting http call!! from the test
    console.log('ngOnInit called !!');
    this.httpClient.get(this.url).subscribe((content) => console.log(content));
  }
```

Comment: Test still fails with all console logs called and a real HTTP call attempt made to example.com, so no success. Still at a dead end. I have also tried mocking the HttpClient but that doesn't change the result either...

Comment: It is strange that a real HTTP call is made when we are using `HttpClientTestingModule`. Sorry, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out myself. The issue was I was importing `HttpClientModule` into the component, whereas this should only be imported once into the application.

`imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],`

Removing this solved it:

`imports: [CommonModule],`